# SharePoint multiple lists feeding master list

Tags: sharepoint-2010

forgive me; i don't have much sharepoint experiance. I'm using 2010 and unfortunately I cannot use sharepoint design or any other thrid party editors due to company restricitons.

I have a list that contains all the fields I am attempting to collect from various groups. most of the fields will be entered by all the groups however there are a few exceptions. I want to either have multiple lists that feed a master list or multiple forms that feed one list. A coo-worker who is too busy to elaborate suggested to make site columns (done) and then a content type for the list (done) and when i create a new list it will feed the master list but i assume i'm missing something (it also doesn't make sense to me how they would be linked in this way but again i'm new to SP). from the limited time i had to discuss this with my coo-worker he said that editing or removing a record from either list will remove it from the other list (which is desirable to me)

this sounds dumb but i cannot have all the fields available to all the groups because i will have issues with the groups entering data in the fields that are not associated with them.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the intent correctly you have the following setup...

- Group A List
- Group B List
- Group C List

You want to have a list column with the same values available in each Group list such as **Group Child Column**. The Group Child Column might have values such as A, B, C but, you want those to be tied to a list.

If I understand correctly the way I would do this would be to create a custom list *Group Child List* to hold the values for the *Group Child Column*.

Then on each Group List I would create a column entitled *Group Child Column* and make the column type a Lookup (information already on this site) which you would then have it pull it's information from the *Group Child List* list.

Does that help?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't think I was detailed enough in my question. lets say I have a list with fields: Name, SS#, Depatment, Address and i have 3 groups i want group A to input Name and SS# and Group B to input Name, SS#, and Depatment and group C to input Name, SS#, Depatment, Address. having it on all on one list (or being able to remove it from one list and have those same records found on other lists al removed) is desirable due to the volume this will have which is being managed by linking the list to an access table and running a macro to "Archive" the data no longer needed in real time

Comment: Based on what you described I think @tsap has the right idea. If you simply don't want each group to see each other's data then you can create unique views for each group.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is just to create a few views - one for every group. This way each group can see only the fields they are interested in. However, when a group will be adding/updating an item, all fields will be available. Unfortunately, it's not possible to change that without SharePoint Designer, coding or 3rd party solution.